# How to transform fire particle in Anime studio

Tags: animation, anime-studio

I want to create animation of meteor 's moving in sky , this meteor has fire ,

for its flame/fire i draw a fire and then use particle , but now I can't control completely whole fire :

fire must be exit from one whole on the meteor

in frame 0 all thing is correct as you can see in this picture:

[image]

in the frame 6 meteor move up so fire must move up but when I translate particle's layer to up  , fire traverse circular path as you can see in this picture :

[image]

how can I choose setting to create correct animation ?

Comment: I dont know that anyone here is currently familiar with Anime Studio but after two days I'm willing to put a bounty on it to attract more attention. Sounds interesting to me.